OpenMPI java binding on Mac with M1: (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')
I have already installed the open-mpi by command arch -x86_64 brew reinstall --build-from-source open-mpi and run the terminal under Rosetta.
In the terminal the command arch return with i386, and run mpirun java will still result:
mpi java lib failed to load: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.3_1/lib/libmpi_java.40.dylib: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.3_1/lib/libmpi_java.40.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.3_1/lib/libmpi_java.40.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.3_1/lib/libmpi_java.40.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/5.0.3_1/lib/libmpi_java.40.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))

I have tried run with arch -x86_64 but I think this might not be the reason of this problem. Is there other possible way to run OpenMPI Java Binding on arm64? Or I need to install JDK under x86 with rosetta again.

you should try running native instead of x86_64 binaries via rosetta.

running native does not work. It works for simple HelloWorld, but whenever the program call an mpi function it returns the error

you installed Open MPI for x86_64 so you are clearly not running native.

I tried run java binding before installing Rosetta 2 ,which makes it run under arm64. And it didn't work (return the same message), would that need some configuration when install OpenMPI with enable java binding?

have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64' suggests you are not running native!

Thanks for the clarification! I just found it is my fault during make file process which make it install x86 binaries file
